# ISTIO sidecar for distributed tracing using Jaegar

Tags: kubernetes, microservices, istio, distributed-tracing

Evaluating Istio Sidecar proxies around the feature of distributed tracing, currently i am passing the tracing headers and accepting those as a part of the application code, Below are the headers:

```
  "x-request-id"

  "x-b3-spanid"

  "x-b3-parentspanid"

  "x-b3-sampled"

  "x-b3-flags"

  "x-ot-span-context"
```

Is there a way where in these headers could be configured to be passed with requests at POD/ingress level so that i do not have to make any changes in the code in order to achieve the tracing between the services?

Comment: https://istio.io/docs/tasks/telemetry/distributed-tracing/jaeger/

Comment: Thats via passing headers in the application code.. can we keep the application agnoist of this?

Comment: This is [discussed in the Istio FAQ](https://istio.io/faq/distributed-tracing#istio-copy-headers).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [Virtual Service to add headers to any requests that gets routed by it](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/v1alpha3/virtual-service/?_ga=2.117117646.993977806.1566388284-1019622628.1562665692#Headers):

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: sample-route
spec:
  hosts:
  - '*'
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: app.prod.svc.cluster.local
      headers:
        request:
          add:
            key1: value1
            key2: value2
```

From there, you can attach the `Virtual Service` to a `Gateway` for your `Ingressgateway`.

Comment: But the values here value1 value2 could those be on per request basis?

Comment: Every request that goes through the route will be tagged.